# Saving a string until a last delimiter is found - C

Tags: c, string, strtok

Is it possible to use strtok or some other string function to cut the string until the point where last delimiter is found.

Specific example would be date; I would like to transform "4.1.2017." to "4.1.2017" - without the dot at the end.

Comment: As a comment, it's worthwhile noting that `strtok` is obsoleted by `strsep` but if you are to use `strtok` its worthwhile using `strtok_r` as it's thread safe and re-entrant.

Comment: my question is: why would you use a complicated function to delete a dot at the end ? could you elaborate on the possible complication in that task ?

Comment: It is an assignment which touches on subject of file handling, string manipulation and structures. We are expected to scan data from a file, manipulate it and then print it on a separate file.  
I agree it is stupid, but we have to upload the code on the server which evalautes it and it has to be written in that format.

Comment: Just create a Function which goes through the whole buffer until end and for each delimiter found save it (its position) into a variable then move to next character found until (maybe) you get another delimiter. Save its position to that variable and return the function with that. Rest is easy to do it if you know the position of that delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a single delimiter, use [`strrchr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strrchr.html) to find its last occurrence in the string:

```
char str[] = "quick.brown.fox";
char *ptr = strrchr(str, '.');
if (ptr) {
    *ptr = '\0';
}
printf("%s\n"' str);
```

This [produces the following output](http://ideone.com/uj8kJV):

```
quick.brown
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I explained in My comment (if you don't want to use `strrchr` or you cannot for some reasons)  I'll create a Function which checks the position of that delimiter like this:

```
int my_strrchr(const char *ptr, const char delimiter){
    if (ptr == NULL ){
        printf("Error, NULL Pointer\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if ( *ptr == '\0' ){
        printf("Error, the Buffer is Empty\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int i = 0;
    int ret = 0;

    while( ptr[i] != '\0' ){
        if ( ptr[i] == delimiter ){
            ret = i;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

And use it Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char arr[] = "4.1.2017.";
    char delimiter = '.';

    int len;

    if( (len = my_strrchr(arr, delimiter)) > 0){
        while ( arr[len] != '\0'){
            arr[len] = '\0';
        }
        printf("%s\n", arr);
    }
}
```

See [DEMO](http://ideone.com/qDTuEj).
Any way this is only to get you an Idea and as you can see I use no standard Functions here.